# How to overwrite A flexform of repository extension in to the Site Package in order to change the configuration

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x, powermail, flexform

Are there any docs that can help me to overwrite the Flexform of powermail extension into my site package? So that I can edit the field configuration.

Please help, I have been searching for this very long.

Thank you.

Comment: You are setting a new XML-file for an existing field. So, yes, you have to use the identifier of the plugin you want to override. (@Alex, there's a bug in the blog post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in ext_localconf.php

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_userauth.php']['postUserLookUp'][] = \ABC\MyPackage\Hooks\OverwriteFlexForm::class . '->overwrite';
```

In OverwriteFlexForm.php:

```
    <?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace ABC\MyPackage\Hooks;

/**
 * Class OverwriteFlexForm
 */
class OverwriteFlexForm
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $path = 'FILE:EXT:my_package/Configuration/FlexForms/FlexformStudyfinderList.xml';

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function overwrite()
    {
        $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['pi_flexform']['config']['ds']['powermail_pi1,list']
            = $this->path;
    }
}
```

In FlexformStudyfinderList.xml:

```
Flexform Code goes here.
```

Finally, I have found the solution myself. Thanks, everyone for your support.